# Problem with ThingsBoard temperature script

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

There is a problem with the Thingsboard script, I'm supposed to take a critical temperature from the device 8 times and create an alarm, but I either don't get the logic or something, the problem is that I need to display the IN type 8 times and the OUT type 9 times in the debug mode which means that an alarm is created and a message is sent[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxmLP.png)

My script:

```
var newMsg = {};
var newCounter;

metadata.criticalTemperatureCount = metadata.criticalTemperatureCount || 0;

if (msg.deviceAge > 5 && msg.temperature > -10) {
    metadata.criticalTemperatureCount++;
}

if (metadata.criticalTemperatureCount >= 8) {
    metadata.alarm = {
        severity: 'CRITICAL',
        message: ''
    };

    metadata.criticalTemperatureCount = 0;
}

newCounter = metadata.criticalTemperatureCount;
newMsg.counter = newCounter;

return {
    msg: msg.temperature,
    metadata: metadata
};
```

Comment: You cant create additional output messages with script node, it always returns 1 OUT message for 1 IN message.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info, but it was worth a try :D